# ASP.NET What is this called using from keyword to loop through list

Tags: asp.net

Hey I just wanted to find out the working of the following script as I never seen "From" used like this before

```
              var formattedList = from a in value
              select new
              {
                   a.value,
                   currencyId = a.currencyId == -1 ? "" : a.currencyId + ""
              };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax your looking a LINQ query which uses LAMBDA expressions:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

There are various ways to use LINQ, check out those pages for some examples

Answer (score 0):

That's LINQ :) There's a pretty good summary [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query).